# Using CAST with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table(students):

```
id | name  | address
1  | hello | test451.1
2  | hello | test461.1
```

I want to select the rows that contain `451` in the address field exact before decimal and after alphabet string. Basically I want to filter `451` from address values. I am using the following query to get integer out of string.

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE CAST(`address` AS UNSIGNED) = '451'
```

I still have no idea how to filter for a float.

Also tried this but didn't work :

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE CAST(`address` AS DECIMAL(4,1)) = '451'
```

I can't use like %451% because there are other rows with test4451.1, test 5441.1 etc. I don't want to select them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `substring` and `position` to figure out 451

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE  
substring(address,position('4' in address),4)= '451.'
```

here is the link i try with your data and it returns

```
create table students (
id int,name varchar(50),address varchar(300)
);
insert into students values(1,'hello','test451.1'),(2,'hello','test461.1'),(3,'hell','test 5441.1');

id  name    address
1   hello   test451.1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c6byWF6ahoBusWQqqNtsSf/0

Comment: There is one problem. Its also picking up the rows which has values like test4511.1 . It shouldn't select those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `like`:

```
where address like '%451%'
```

You can use:

```
where address like 'test451.%'
```

Comment: I can't use like because there are other rows with address as test4451, test5451 . I must use =  .

Comment: @JasminderPalSingh . . . It is unclear what you are asking.  Why not just use `=`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
Actually, I can't use = because the user input coming as integer(451) but field has value in string format having float. So i must filter exact results.

Comment: Please check Zaynul Abadin Tuhin answer. It worked but there is one issue as written in answer comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(25.65 AS int);
```

That is what [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp) says. That should get the integer out of string.